# Mi4I not showing logcat

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.1, and trying to get the logcat of the application installed on device Mi4i(Lollipop), adb is working fine but logcat is empty in android studio. Is something wrong with the device? because everything looks fine with another android device.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps in Android Studio:

1. Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB integration

(Uncheck and check again if it is already checked)

> I was facing similar issue, this worked for me.